# Driving license renewal in USA (Louisiana)

Tags: usa, driving-license

One year ago my wife (J-1) and I (J-2) moved to the USA for her postdoctoral research.

Back then I got my EAD (Employment Authorization Document), then I got my SSN and finally I was able to get my driving license with one year of validity.

Recently we got our new DS-2019 papers renewing our statuses for one more year. So I applied for an EAD renewal (case still being reviewed) and when our driver licenses expired we went to OMV. My wife got her new driver license without issues, but mine was stuck on something USCIS-related and the person asked me to try again in 2 weeks.

I did return in 2 weeks, but my case was still under review. They asked me to try again in a couple of days. I did, same thing happened all over again.

I now have a SAVE Verification Case Number which is way more than 20 working days under review, which is likely to be preventing me to get my renewed driver license.

Could this be related to my EAD renewal still being under review? Any advices on how could I sort out this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a REAL ID or non-REAL ID driver's license?

Comment: My current expired driver license is a non real id one

Comment: then it shouldn't matter whether you have an EAD as you are applying based on your J-2 status

Comment: I agree, I'm still trying to figure out what else might be blocking me, maybe I'll have to get an appointment with USCIS to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this issue was caused by a mistake by the DMV and it's not related to EAD at all. They were not attaching my documentation properly so my case was in a forever pending state. The people that work at the DMV were not recognizing this scenario and they wouldn't allow me to speak to a supervisor either. I had to contact my University Director, she contacted a DMV director and only then a manager accepted to review my case and attach my documentation properly. This took me 3 months and 9 visits to the DMV, it would be resolved so much easier if they allowed me to speak to a supervisor in the first place. I know there are other people with similar situation so this is probably caused by lack of training when dealing with J-2 visa holders.